# Edit android ninepatch png programly (change color)

Tags: android, image, png, edit, nine-patch

Is there a way to change color of a ninepatch image(png) programly on android ? I know how do this with bitmap but not with ninepatch...

Thanks to helping me.

Regards
Jim

Answer (score 1):

NinePatch images are standard PNG files, with a 1-pixel border around the outside to mark the repeated areas. You can edit them in any image editor, and as long as you leave the 1-pixel outer border alone, they'll continue to work just fine.

[See here for how they are constructed](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Comment: Thanks but I would like to modify it programly. Sorry I forgot to tell in the subject.

Comment: did u get ur answer, m searching for the answer of this question

Comment: No answer I just make one ninepath in all color i want... Always search for doing this

Comment: Did you try to apply filters or whatever to a bitmap loaded from your drawable? As long as it is a PNG you should be just fine. Proper naming may be required. I think you may need to make a [NinePatchDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html) from the bitmap you updated. Then you can use [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) (deprecated since API 16 but has a replacement).